# MySQL calculating difference between values where not BETWEEN x and y

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query (roughly the below) which looks up a table to determine the values that do not fall within recommended guidelines;

```
SELECT 
    location.name, test.name, result.value
FROM
    results
        INNER JOIN
    location ON location.id = results.locationid
        INNER JOIN
    tests ON tests.id = results.testid
WHERE
    result.value NOT BETWEEN test.lowerlimit AND test.upperlimit
GROUP BY location.name
```

This returns the tests that are outside of the range, and I then had planned to calculate the difference between the recommended range and the result I have. The issue I have is that sometimes the exceedance will be below the range, other times it will be above it so I cant just do (`result.value - test.upperlimit`).

Is there a way I can include something like an `IF` statement in there, to say if the result is `< lowerlimit` then calculate `results.value - test.lowerlimit`, or if it is `> upperlimit` then calculate `results.value - test.upperlimit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at MySQL [control flow functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Following is an example using `IF` function:

```
SELECT 
    location.name, 
    test.name, 
    IF (result.value < test.lowerlimit, results.value - test.lowerlimit, results.value - test.upperlimit)
FROM
    results
        INNER JOIN
    location ON location.id = results.locationid
        INNER JOIN
    tests ON tests.id = results.testid
WHERE
    result.value NOT BETWEEN test.lowerlimit AND test.upperlimit
GROUP BY location.name
```

You can use `CASE` statement also like the following in `SELECT`:

```
CASE 
WHEN result.value < test.lowerlimit THEN 
    results.value - test.lowerlimit 
ELSE 
    results.value - test.upperlimit 
END
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that is exactally what I was after! :)